# Import from Excel using jxl.jar isn't working for List Values

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I use jxl.jar for importing data from the exce. For Text Field type the import is working fine. But 'List Field Type' it isn't working. Can anyone pls help me out. [image: This is the type of fields we have]

```
          driver.findElement(By. id( "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_SalutationName_I" )).sendKeys(sh.getCell(0, 1).getContents());
```

In the above image we have 'Industry' as List field type.
i Have tried with xpath also still i have the problem with that List Field type.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to send values to a "Select" dropdown. You should rather use the below code to set the value. **Assuming the given id is for a dropdown and the getContents() returns an option to be selected from the dropdown**:

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_SalutationName_I")));
sel.selectByVisibleText(sh.getCell(0, 1).getContents());
```

Comment: im getting this exception.  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"

Comment: Is the id **ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_SalutationName_I** of the select dropdown "industry"? If not, please put the id of the dropdown in the code above..